# Quero apagar sempre o primeiro índice a cada clique em um botão. Como faço?

Tags: javascript, array, slice

Visto o que tentei:

```
<html>

<body>
<script>
    var nome = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

    var remover = nome.slice(0);

    function shuffle(array) {
        return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 1);
        remover.splice(array, 1);
    }

    shuffle(nome);

    alert(nome);
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Mas não soube agregar um botão para tal finalidade e ainda este código não faz o propósito.

Comment: testa `el.addEventListener('click', function(){ nome.shift(); });` Se não funcionar ou não for o que queres tens de explicar melhor a pergunta....

Comment: O método `shuffle()` está retornando um valor antes de você executar o `splice()` , talvez isso seja o problema.

Comment: @DiegoHenrique o que eu quis dizer é que se o seu botão executa o método `shuffle(array)`, o problema está no fato de que ele executa `return (Math.round(Math.random()) - 1); ` antes de executar `remover.splice(array, 1);`, sendo assim o  método retorna antes do  `splice()` ser executado, e isso pode ser o problema no seu código.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O teu código está um bocado confuso e não está a coincidir com o que pedes no titulo, aqui está o que pedes no titulo da pergunta:

```js
var first_ele;
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var nome = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  first_ele = nome.shift();
  console.log(first_ele, nome)
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">apagar primeiro ele</button>
```

Com [`splice()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) farias:

```
...
first_ele = nome.splice(0, 1);
...
```